# CONCAT string and INT in MYSQL and export big mysql table to small csv files

Tags: mysql, int, concatenation

I am new in MYSQL programming. I want to select into outfile a very big table into several csv files using MYSQL loop script. My script is as following:

```
BEGIN
        SET @t_lines=0;
        SET @t_count=0;
        SET @t_filepath='/home/ab/path/table_name_02212013_';
        WHILE t_lines<=5000000
        SET @t_filename=CONCAT(@t_filepath,CAST(@t_count as CHAR));
        select * into outfile @t_filename fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' from table_name limit @t_lines,@t_lines+300000;
        SET @t_lines= @t_lines+300000;
        SET @t_count= @t_count+1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
END
```

I got a syntax error in line:

> SET @t_filename=CONCAT(@t_filepath,CAST(@t_count as CHAR));

The syntax error caused by WHILE ... DO. Thanks for quick reply.
Here I still have syntax error at "@t_lines,@t_lines+300000" after "limit". 
I figure it out, seems "limit" not allowed "@t_lines+300000" to give the line range. It can be fixed by giving a new variable:

```
   BEGIN
            DECLARE t_lines INT DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE t_count INT DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE t_endlines INT DEFAULT 300000;
            DECLARE t_linerange INT DEFAULT 300000;
            SET @t_filepath='/home/ab/path/table_name_02212013_';
            WHILE t_lines<=5000000 DO
            SET @t_filename=CONCAT(@t_filepath,CAST(@t_count as CHAR));
            select * into outfile '@t_filename' fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' from table_name limit t_lines,t_endlines;
            SET t_lines= t_lines+t_linerange;
            SET t_endlines= t_endlines+t_linerange
            SET t_count= t_count+1;
            END WHILE;
            COMMIT;
    END
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

The [syntax for a `WHILE` loop in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html) requires a `DO`;

```
WHILE t_lines<=5000000 DO
...
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Thanks, will never forget "DO" after using WHILE again

Answer (score 1):

The filename argument for `INTO OUTFILE` [must be a literal string](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13870).  You can't use variables or expressions as the filename.

The arguments to `LIMIT` must be integer constants.  You can use parameter placeholders (`?`), or stored procedure parameters or local procedure variables (the ones you [DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare.html)).  But you [can't use session variables](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8094) (the ones with `@` prefix), [nor can you use expressions](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6673).

You're going to have to create the query as an SQL string, interpolating the values into the string.
Then use that SQL string with [`PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: thanks very much for pointing out the errors. Already change to use Global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
convert(columnName, char)
```

-->

```
BEGIN
        SET @t_lines=0;
        SET @t_count=0;
        SET @t_filepath='/home/ab/path/table_name_02212013_';
        WHILE t_lines<=5000000
        SET @t_filename=CONCAT(@t_filepath,convert(@t_count, CHAR));
        select * into outfile @t_filename fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' from table_name limit @t_lines,@t_lines+300000;
        SET @t_lines= @t_lines+300000;
        SET @t_count= @t_count+1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
END
```